# Mono / MonoDevelop: Get solution version at runtime

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I am looking to retrieve the application version (essentially the `<ReleaseVersion>` property in the solution file) at runtime.  How does one access this via code?

Comment: I too would like an answer, as this property seems to be ignored even when an AssemblyInfo.cs is absent.

Answer (score 6):

The standard way of setting the application version in .NET (and therefore presumably MONO) is to use the `AssemblyVersion` attribute. This is normally specified in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, but can be specified in other files, as is shown below.

To get the version at runtime, you can use the [AssemblyName.Version property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). The following is a slightly modified version of the code from the given link:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The version of the currently executing assembly is: {0}",
          Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
    }
}
```

When compiled and run, it produces this:

> The version of the currently executing assembly is: 1.1.0.0

The above was tested on both .NET (Visual Studio 2010), and Mono 3.0 (compiled using `mcs` from the command line, not Mono Develop).

Comment: Why is it that when you navigate to the Project in MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio --> Options --> General --> Main Settings --> Version this property does nothing?

Comment: @StephenFurlani - sorry, I don't use Mono Develop so I have no clue on that.

Comment: That's kindof the issue.  The project settings are ignored, so why even have project settings for that?

Comment: @StephenFurlani - I think there are two questions here. 1) How to get/retrieve the application version in Mono/.Net. 2) Why does setting the application version in the Mono Develop IDE not work? The answer to the former is written above. The answer to the latter I don't know. It's probably a bug.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you right-click a project, properties, application, assembly information, and set the version, which corresponds to AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion in AssemblyInfo.cs. However, in Xamarin Studio or MonoDevelop, you right-click a project, options, main settings, and set version... It doesn't change AssemblyInfo.cs.  Instead, it modifies the csproj.  I'm not sure how/if this metadata can be accessed at runtime.

Comment: -1. As others have said, this doesn't work in MonoDevelop because `AssemblyInfo.cs` isn't updated automatically - and this question is specifically about MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the suggestions in this forum  --> [get current version](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2278/how-do-you-get-current-version-information-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly hack, but you can utilise the `BeforeBuild` target to write that property to a file, which you then promptly include as an embedded resource. In your *.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="release-version.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- .... -->

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="echo $(ReleaseVersion) &gt;release-version.txt" />
</Target>
```

....then in your C♯ code, you could create a property like this:

```
public static string Version {
    get {
        using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("SBRL.GlidingSquirrel.release-version.txt")))
        {
            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

This should work on all major operating systems. Don't forget:

- To add `using System.Reflection;` to the top of your file if you haven't already
- To add the `release-version.txt` file to your version control's ignore list (e.g. `.gitignore`, etc.)