# Xamarin Studio: Get solution version at runtime

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Under *Project > Project folder settings > Main settings* one can define a version number.

[image: version number in main settings]

How can I get the version number at runtime in my iOS app?

I tried the solution posted in [Mono / MonoDevelop: Get solution version at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350577/mono-monodevelop-get-solution-version-at-runtime) but I only get 0.0.0.0 despite it should be 0.1. I know you can use `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString`, but for what is this field used?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary [new NSString ("CFBundleShortVersionString")].ToString ();
NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary [new NSString ("CFBundleVersion")].ToString ();
```

Comment: It also works without `new NSString ("")`. But for what is the version number in Xamarin Studio used? The one you posted is from iOS directly.

Comment: @testing That version isn't used for iOS apps.

Comment: @Krumelur: Yeah, the `CFBundleShortVersionString` is only needed when submitting to the app store. But the version is shown to the user which you set it iTunes Connect as i know. What usecase does this additional version from Xamarin Studio have?

Comment: I presume the idea of *that* version is that it should automatically update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file; but it doesn't. Could be a bug.

Comment: @Krumelur: Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to read that value out?

Comment: You can get the assembly version but if you can access that field directly I don't know.